# Joining worker nodes to kubernetes cluster hangs forever

Tags: kubernetes

I've created my Kubernetes cluster with command

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 192.168.0.0/16
```

I installed the Calico network add-on on my control plane node

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.25.0/manifests/calico.yaml
```

I have two worker nodes servers and I'm trying to joing them to my cluster with command

```
sudo kubeadm join IP_OF_MY_SERVER:6443 --token ... --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:...
```

but it hangs forever and nothing happens. It happens on both worker nodes servers.
I have full connectivity on my worker nodes, I can reach internet and I can reach my control plane node by IP and hostname. My cluster is alive.

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION
k8s-control   Ready    control-plane   5h12m   v1.26.1
```

```
kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://172.31.97.251:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://172.31.97.251:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

I am running my cluster and worker nodes on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Jammy, containerd version 1.6

```
containerd --version
containerd containerd.io 1.6.18 2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
```

kubelet at version 1.26.1

```
kubelet --version
Kubernetes v1.26.1
```

kubectl at 1.26

```
Client Version: version.Info Major:"1", Minor:"26"
```

My containerd is up and running on `systemd`

```
sudo systemctl status containerd
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-02-27 21:40:01 UTC; 52min ago
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I checked system logs on my worker nodes and this is what I see

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog
Feb 27 22:19:17 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 27 22:19:17 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 187.
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 kubelet[9361]: E0227 22:19:27.903339    9361 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to validate kubelet flags: the container runtime endpoint address was not specified or empty, use --container-runtime-endpoint to set"
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 27 22:19:27 k8s-worker-1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to explicitly tell kubelet where to find the containerd socket. In the */etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service*, add this line as an argument to the kubelet executable (usually `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kubelet`):

```
    --container-runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Verify the location of the containerd.sock. If it is not in /run/containerd.containerd.sock, you can find it by looking in the */etc/containerd/config.toml* file under

```
[grpc]
address = "/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
```

If the kubelet.service file is not in that location, it can be found by running `systemctl status kubelet` and looking at the **Loaded:** line.

Finally, `systemctl restart kubelet`.